# Create a list of combinations? Lua/Pseudocode

Tags: lua

So I want to multiply all values in a list by 3 different values and then sum all values up.

```
List( 1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
List2(-1, 0, 1)
```

Would look like:

```
-1-2-3-4
0-2-3-4
1-2-3-4
-1+0-3-4
-1+2-3-4
-1-2+0-4
```

And so on going through every possible combination, where each member of List is multiplied by a member of List2 and the resulting list is summed up.
I've no code yet, other than a for-loop going through List.

Please let me know how I might improve this post.

Comment: Please add the code you have (even if it's not much). Where do you get your list of numbers from?

Comment: Do you also want to have the sum of say `0*1 + 0*2 + -1*3 + 1*4`? So with multiple numbers multiplied by different numbers in List2 at the same time

Comment: your title says "create a list" but your post describes a single sum. so what is it?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer it's two sets of numbers and the second list is just -1, 0, 1

Comment: @Piglet technically I want to save the list of multipliers that produces a certain sum

Comment: @Anderium yes, that should be included

Comment: @Jokru then you can just write `return 0` because the `1` and `-1` will cancel each other out all the time.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer no, as I want them summed up separately not all together

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I only want each number from List included once then that multiplied by one of List2, and if the sum of that product equals a certain number save those products

Comment: I'll post all the code once I get on my PC

Answer (score 1):

It seems I misunderstood your question the first time.

What you want is a bit more complicated than what I initially thought, but it's not too hard.

Let's call your lists A and B for simplicity; for every value in A you have size(B) possible factors; so you get size(B)^size(A) permutations.

You can represent these permutations as base-size(B) numbers. For example, say B has 3 elements and A has 4 (as in your example), then you can represent each permutation as a 4-digit base-3 number: 0000<sub>3</sub>, 1000<sub>3</sub>, 2000<sub>3</sub>, 0100<sub>3</sub>, etc.

The largest number is 2222<sub>3</sub>, which is 3<sup>4</sup>-1

Generally speaking, you need to count from 0 to base<sup>exponent</sup>-1 and map each integer to a unique sum, where each summand corresponds to one digit in the integer: the first one being your first vector indexed with the position of the digit and the other the second vector indexed with the digit itself.

```lua
local A = {1, 2, 3, 4}
local B = {-1, 0, 1}

local function decompose(number, base, exponent)
  local sum = 0
  local buf = {}
  for i=1,#exponent do
    local n = math.floor(number / (#base)^(i-1)) % (#base)
    sum = sum + exponent[i] * base[n+1]
  end
  return sum
end

for i=0,(#B)^(#A)-1 do
  print(i, decompose(i, B, A))
end
```